# How to get intellisense when doing XAML data bindings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, xaml, intellisense

It would be nice if in XAML when I define ItemsControl/ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableContracts}" that Visual Studio would be smart enough to go find the property AvailableContracts on the ModelView which the DataContext is bound to, reflect it, and then when I type:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=
```

it would **pop up intellisense of the bindable properties that are available to me** in my ContractModelView since AvailableContracts is a List collection.

**I don't see why Visual Studio can't go follow this logical path and give me the needed intellisense. Can anyone explain what the disconnect here is?** Or surely there is some way to "give it some help" so that it could provide intellisense. Any third-party tools to do this? Perhaps in VS2010? I hear MEF is going to make intellisense much better in VS2010, hope so.

This lack of databinding intellisense when writing my XAML views just feels like notepad. :-(

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="TestMvvmWpf8898.Views.CustomerView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableContracts}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NEED_INTELLISENSE_HERE
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is only one good solution for your problem: Resharper

Answer (score 0):

It is possible from Visual Studio 2013 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/09/xaml-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx